# Scaling graphic assets vs calculating graphic assets size for different screen resolutions

Tags: java, android, ios, unity-game-engine

Is it a best practice to calculate EXACT graphic assets' size for different screen resolution to increase performance? Or is it good enough to just calculate approximate final size of those assets and then scale them so they won't lose sharpness/details?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer with all the different things you've tagged.

On a modern mobile platform, the compositing is probably GPU-side. The image will cover the same number of pixels regardless of the texture size, which means it'll run the pixel shader the same number of times. You may see moderate variation in how fast the pixel shader runs based on whether the texture fits into the GPU's texture cache. Smaller is better and dimensions that are powers of 2 are usually better.

Aside from speed, if you match the exact size it'll be visually crisper because it avoids resampling.

If it's CPU side, making it the exact right size will probably skip rescaling altogether and be much, much faster. (By CPU standards at least, either way you're better off on the GPU)

Edit: And of course the real answer is to measure the frame rate difference in your particular situation, instead of asking the internet. :)